# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Hello#index ( ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack

I have downloaded the [Honeybadger webpack example](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-rails-webpacker-example) and run `bundle install`.

I don't have any errors in terminal, yet get the following when I start my server:

```
Webpacker can't find application.js in /Users/admin/Documents/sourcemap/honeybadger-rails-webpacker-example/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. Webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your Webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

It applies to the line `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>`

Where can be my problem?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem.  Fix was:

1. Run "bundle exec rails webpacker:install" in the console to upgrade to the latest version of webpacker
2. Find out that my node version (8.6.0) was incompatible with the current version of webpack
3. Use NVM to upgrade to Node 10.16.0
4. Rerun "bundle exec rails webpacker:install" in the console (not sure if this was necessary)

At the end of this it started working!

Comment: just doing `bundle exec rails webpacker:install` worked for me. Thanks! Had to say `no` to any potential overwrites during this step.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was because i was setting `extract_css: true` but i didn't import any css