# Ruby on Rails (Agile book example) error: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Store#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

Please note that I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails and here. This seems to me like a near repeat of other not-resolved questions such as [Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in .... localhost:3000/* errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379731/webpackermanifestmissingentryerror-in-localhost3000-errors/65485268#65485268) but I was asked to repost it as a new thread:

I am working through the depot examples in Agile Web Development with Rails 6, but there is a consistent error when dealing with `\app\views\layout\application.html.erb` when it encounters
`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

```
Showing /Users/rogerburks/Documents/rubyVacation/depot2/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Webpacker can't find application in /Users/rogerburks/Documents/rubyVacation/depot2/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
```

This is happening in development and occurs when I load the views in localhost:3000. I have faced the same error over 3 days of trying to fix it as a new Agile reader, even creating new projects and starting over. Having tried to explore the 4 presented options as best I can, and having googled the error and tried some attempted solutions, I decided that it would be far more efficient for me to ask here rather than to continue flailing.

I suspect that my project is being built in a way that breaks it. This describes the issue without telling how to fix it: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.

I suspect that I may have either installed a webpacker that is too new for my configuration, or I have not properly installed a dependency. Either way, Rails does not generate something that will work with the book's examples.

`config/webpacker.yml` looks like this:

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true
  compile: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Comment: I had this issue and what solved it for me was making sure my version of node worked.  This is what helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069687/webpackermanifestmissingentryerror-in-helloindex-ruby-on-rails

Comment: This is in fact one of the threads that I have tried. I now have the n node version manager installed because of this. I can switch node versions fairly easily, but so far none have worked. I don't know exactly if there is a known version of node that works with the latest webpacker, but I think I have both updated to current with my application now. I have also tried some older node installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the bright idea run the book's downloadable example folder separately, since in general the downloaded examples work.

After editing the project's gemfile to help it recognize that I am using Ruby 2.7.2 instead of Ruby 2.6.5, I ran
`gem install bundler` and then `bundle install` and then I started the server. Somehow, the project itself now runs.

My next task is to figure out why it works. The file `webpacker.yml` only differs in that I had added `compile: true` to the default configuration while flailing, which probably did not break anything. This eliminates settings in this file as a possible cause.

Incidentally, this also "solves" the problem in that it provides a set of steps that can lead to a solution in this specific case. It does not explain exactly why the problem occurred, but most likely I would find that some dependency was not installed right.